# Incorrect result of the Rx.combineLatest function

Tags: flutter, rxdart

I try to handle form with `rxdart` streams to check error on input text field and make decision based on `combineLatest3` to submit or do not submit the form.
First field input value must be with length 3.
Second and third input fields are similar - there should be double value like `102.5` for example. But if input is `102,5` (notice the difference) then it is not a valid input.
Here are the rules based on stream transformers.

```
// `first`, `second` and `third` are BehaviourSubject<String> from rxdart



  final validateFirst = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (first, sink) {
      if (rapport.length != 3) {
        sink.addError('first error');
      } else {
        sink.add(first);
      }
    },
  );

  final validateSecond = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (second, sink) {
      try {
        double.parse(second);
        sink.add(second);
      } catch (error) {
        debugPrint('from second: ${error.toString()}');
        sink.addError('second error');
      }
    },
  );

  final validateThird = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (third, sink) {
      try {
        double.parse(third);
        sink.add(third);
      } catch (error) {
        debugPrint('from third: ${error.toString()}');
        sink.addError('third error');
      }
    },
  );
```

and here is a function which makes decision - are those inputs are valid.

```
  // for some reason this gets true when there is an error in `second` stream
  Stream<bool> get isValid => Rx.combineLatest3(first, second, third, (a, b, c) => true);
```

With following inputs, the form is valid.

> 100 (first input field)

> 12,5 (second input field)

> 120.4 (third input field)

with the above combination the `isValid`  returns `true` but the second transformer clearly detect error, i.e. it outputs the following

```
I/flutter ( 3780): 12,5
I/flutter ( 3780): validate second: FormatException: Invalid double
```

Where is the error?

Simplifying the form to two fields (first and second), I noticed that the result of the `isValid` function (with the use of `Rx.combineLatest2`) is the last reaction to check in the corresponding transformer, for example, if you first enter the second field 12,4 (which is not suitable), and then enter the correct one in the first field value with a length of 3, then the form is considered valid - what does this mean?

Comment: where (and how) are you using `isValid`?

Comment: @pskink  `isValid` is using in StreamBuilder which render the submit button i.e. `onPressed: () { if (snapshot.hasData) { bloc.submitData(); Navigator.pop(context); }}`

Comment: so you need to handle errors too: `if (snapshot.hasError) ...`

Comment: @pskink no, it's responsibility of combineLatest in this workflow. I think the reason of that because those input fields of type `digits` and flutter somehow strange interpreters the case when I enter `,` i.e. combineLatest gets the value up to the comma so I have to add one more filter to explicitly detect this case

Comment: so why are you doing `sink.addError('third error')` if you don't use it any way? I mean any error you emit is lost

Comment: @pskink the fact is that when I enter for example `1,5` then the error `third error` displays under the input field, i.e. it cannot be said that it is lost, but it is not processed in that case in combineLatest

Comment: @rozerro Is it possible to get in touch with you? You can find my contacts https://github.com/eugenebrusov